# Performance comparisons betweeen enum evaluations and ints

Tags: c#, enums, performance, integer

Would there be difference in speed between

```
if (myInt == CONST_STATE1)
```

and

```
if (myEnum == myENUM.State1)
```

in c#?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C# Enums are in-lined to be constants by the compilier anyway, so the benefit is code legibility

Comment: Perfect. That actually answers quite a few other questions i had! +1

Comment: You don't happen to know the datatype of such a constant?

Comment: And even if there was a difference it would rarely if ever be significant.

Comment: @Brian how about in 3D calculations?

Comment: The datatype? Its underlying type is an int32 by default, if that's what you mean.

Comment: There's nothing magical about 3d calculations. Why would it be more expensive there?

Comment: @Adam: even for 3d calculations I doubt that you'll be spending a significant amount of time doing these comparisons. If these ifs add up to say 1% of the time, you'll not gain a lot by making it go a little faster.

Comment: @jalf - um, because expense is directly proportional to the number of times an operation runs. Do I need to explain the operation count in even a basic 3D simulation? – Adam Naylor (0 secs ago) [remove this comment]

Comment: Well, it's exactly the same performance. myEnum == myENUM.State1 is translated to int comparison by the JIT. Also, if your enum has fewer options you can change its underlying type to byte or short, and use a smaller data type which usually yields better performance.

Answer (score 2):

The thing to be careful about when using Enums is not to use any of the operations that require reflection (or use them with care).  For example:

1. myEnumValue.ToString().
2. Enum.Parse()
3. Enum.IsDefined()
4. Enum.GetName()
5. Enum.GetNames()

In case of constants the option of doing any operations that require reflection doesn't exist.  However, in case of enums it does.  So you will have to be careful with this.

I have seen profile reports where operations relating to enum validations / reflections took up to 5% of the CPU time (a scenario where enum validations were done on every call to an API method).  This can be greatly reduced by writing a class that caches the results of the reflection of the enum types being used.

Having said that, **I would recommend making the decision of using enum vs. constant based on what makes sense from a design point of view**.  This is while making sure that the team is aware of the performance implications of the operations involving reflection.

Answer (score 1):

Also, I'm not sure you need to be worried about this at all. It does sound like premature optimisation.  I'm sure that in any system, there are bigger bottlenecks than enum comparisons. :)